# Compute complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to derive the complex conjugate of the number $z:=\exp(a\sqrt{1-2b i})$ for $a>0$ and $b>0$. I tried to convert $z$ to standard or polar form but did not know how to deal with the square root. How should I derive the complex conjugate of $z$?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Consider solving the equation: $x+yi=\sqrt{1-2bi}$.